# How to send message without @client.event in discord.py?

Tags: python, multithreading, discord, discord.py, python-multithreading

I need a way to constantly check for the message `'kill'` in discord.py. I have many while loops in my code so I need to create a new thread with the threading module. How can I send a message to a channel with that thread without the events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(channel.send("example message"))`. Use it like this:

```
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

def funct():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(channel.send("example message"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord changed it and you have to use send_message. So something like this: `channel.send_message("Message Here")`